# How can I show svg files on Firefox?

Tags: flutter, web, firefox, svg, flutter-web

I'm trying to display my logo using an svg image using Image.network(path)
It works perfectly on chrome but on a few other browsers(mainly Firefox ) the svg isn't displayed.
Edit: I tried using plugins but with my SVGs they don't work at all

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 383.3 88.7">
    <defs>
        <style>
            .cls-1 {
                fill: #E31949;
            }
        </style>
    </defs>
    <title>Artboard 1</title>
    <path class="cls-1" d="M53.8,0A6.78,6.78,0,0,0,49,2.4L19.5,41.9c-1,1.3-1.8,1.1-1.8-.6V3a3.08,3.08,0,0,0-3-3H3A3.08,3.08,0,0,0,0,3V85.7a3,3,0,0,0,3,3H14.8a3,3,0,0,0,3-3V74a10.25,10.25,0,0,1,1.8-5.4l10-13.3a1.77,1.77,0,0,1,3.2.2L49.4,86.1a5.7,5.7,0,0,0,4.4,2.6H68c1.7,0,2.4-1.2,1.6-2.6l-25.1-46a5,5,0,0,1,.4-5L69.2,2.4C70.1,1.1,69.6,0,68,0Z" />
    <path class="cls-1" d="M79.2,85.7a3,3,0,0,0,3,3H94a3,3,0,0,0,3-3V3a3,3,0,0,0-3-3H82.2a3,3,0,0,0-3,3Z" />
    <path class="cls-1" d="M249.2,55.5c0,1.6-.7,1.8-1.5.4L216.5,2.6A6.05,6.05,0,0,0,212,0H199a3.08,3.08,0,0,0-3,3V85.7a3,3,0,0,0,3,3h11.8a3,3,0,0,0,3-3V33.3c0-1.7.7-1.8,1.5-.4l31.2,53.2a5.89,5.89,0,0,0,4.5,2.6h13a3,3,0,0,0,3-3V3a3.08,3.08,0,0,0-3-3H252.2a3.08,3.08,0,0,0-3,3Z" />
    <path class="cls-1" d="M283.4,85.7a3,3,0,0,0,3,3h11.8a3,3,0,0,0,3-3V3a3.08,3.08,0,0,0-3-3H286.4a3.08,3.08,0,0,0-3,3Z" />
    <path class="cls-1" d="M381.3,51.7a27.6,27.6,0,0,0-5.7-8.5,26.46,26.46,0,0,0-8.5-5.7,28.48,28.48,0,0,0-7.4-1.8,58.79,58.79,0,0,0-6-.3H342c-1.6,0-4.1-.1-5.4-.2l-1.1-.5a9.23,9.23,0,0,1-2.8-1.9,10.65,10.65,0,0,1-1.9-2.8,8.42,8.42,0,0,1-.7-3.5,8.42,8.42,0,0,1,.7-3.5,9,9,0,0,1,4.7-4.7l1.1-.5c1.3-.1,3.7-.2,5.4-.2h34.7a3.08,3.08,0,0,0,3-3V3a3.08,3.08,0,0,0-3-3H342c-1.6,0-4.3.1-6,.3a28.16,28.16,0,0,0-7.3,1.8,27,27,0,0,0-14.1,14.1,25.64,25.64,0,0,0-2.1,10.3,26.12,26.12,0,0,0,2.1,10.4,27.6,27.6,0,0,0,5.7,8.5,27.14,27.14,0,0,0,8.4,5.7,28.16,28.16,0,0,0,7.3,1.8,58.79,58.79,0,0,0,6,.3h11.8c1.6,0,4.1.1,5.4.2l1.1.5a9,9,0,0,1,4.7,4.7,9.1,9.1,0,0,1,0,7,9,9,0,0,1-4.7,4.7l-1.1.5c-1.3.1-3.7.2-5.4.2H320.4a3,3,0,0,0-3,3V85.8a3,3,0,0,0,3,3h33.4c1.6,0,4.3-.1,6-.3a29.41,29.41,0,0,0,7.4-1.8,27.6,27.6,0,0,0,8.5-5.7,27.14,27.14,0,0,0,5.7-8.4,25.64,25.64,0,0,0,2.1-10.3A32.79,32.79,0,0,0,381.3,51.7Z" />
    <path class="cls-1" d="M179.5,17.6a34.89,34.89,0,0,0-5.6-7.2,38.7,38.7,0,0,0-7.2-5.6,41.06,41.06,0,0,0-6-2.8,84.65,84.65,0,0,0-5.6,8.6c-1.3,2.4-2.5,4.9-3.7,7.4.6.2,1.3.4,1.9.6l1.9.3a13.4,13.4,0,0,0,2,.1c2.9,0,4.8,3.2,6.2,5.7a10.84,10.84,0,0,1,.8,1.9,19.19,19.19,0,0,1,.6,10.4,18.62,18.62,0,1,1-32.6-15.9,19.2,19.2,0,0,1,1.4-1.5c4.7-5.2,9.8-4.2,15-2.6a52.51,52.51,0,0,1,2.3-8.4A43.9,43.9,0,0,1,154.8.4a18.48,18.48,0,0,0-2.9-.3c-1.6-.1-4.3-.2-6-.2H116.4a3,3,0,0,0-3,3V85.6a3,3,0,0,0,3,3h11.8a3.08,3.08,0,0,0,3-3V74a3,3,0,0,1,3-3l13.9-.1a5.08,5.08,0,0,1,4.2,2.7L157.7,86a5,5,0,0,0,4.2,2.8h12.9a1.84,1.84,0,0,0,1.8-2.8l-7.5-17.7a3.89,3.89,0,0,1,1.3-4.5,48.14,48.14,0,0,0,4.5-3.9,33,33,0,0,0,5.2-7.2,39.08,39.08,0,0,0,3.3-8.2,33.4,33.4,0,0,0,1.1-8.9,32.35,32.35,0,0,0-1.3-9.4A47.43,47.43,0,0,0,179.5,17.6Z" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Edit the question and put a problem SVG in it. Firefox does not support plugins for SVG display. Its native implementation is better than any plugin.

Comment: @RobertLongson You mean add a tag with problem svg?

Comment: How do I know what's in your SVG image? Edit the question and add its markup.

Comment: Flutter web which is in beta supports only google chrome.

Comment: @Harshapulikollu as far as I know it works everywhere. My problem appears when you use svg images

Comment: Try adding `width` and `height` attributes to your SVG. Maybe Firefox is rendering it with 0 width?

Comment: @Sphinxxx the size is already specified, it wouldn't work without them in chrome either I think. I also just realized that the text padding is slightly smaller too in firefox

Comment: Have you got other SVG (or HTML) elements on the page that also have class `.cls-1` in them?  If so, they could be overriding the style in this SVG. Preventing it from displaying properly.

Comment: @Sphinxxx Turns out that Firefox does render this with size 0 as someone from the Firefox forum pointed out, but I'm still not sure why this happens only on Firefox.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I just searched for .cls-1, haven't found it anywhere else.

Comment: Make sure either the SVG or one of its ancestor elements (eg probably `div` elements) has been given some sort of explicit size.  If the browser can't determine what size something should be, then it can collapse to 0x0. Browser behaviour varies on this.